# Использование html тегов в передаче ajax

Tags: ajax, html

Здравствуйте, начал изучать ajax посредством jQuery, со страницы передаю метод POST на другую страницу, и принимаю от туда же текст и вывожу на страницу, но теги `<p>`, `<br />` так и опечатываются. Как сделать, чтобы они выполняли свою функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. data - полученные данные
2. `$('body').html($('body').html()+data)`